# Fluent nHibernate not returning data

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a small POC application that I am working with, using nHibernate. This is my first time setting nHibernate up on my own, but I have worked with it before. For some reason, my queries are not returning any data. I can confirm I have one `Product` in my database.

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static String _connectionString =
        @"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestProject;User ID=TestProjectMvc;Password=Pa$$word";

    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
                InitializeSessionFactory();

            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    private static void InitializeSessionFactory()
    {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(_connectionString).ShowSql()
            ).Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Product>())
            //.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

My mapping class:

```
 public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
 {
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        References(x => x.Category).Column("CategoryId");
    }
 }
```

And the method I am using to retrieve the data:

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            var list = session.QueryOver<Product>().List();
            return list;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are your mappings and domain objects in the same assembly?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Ahh that was it... I changed my `Mappings` to load from `ProductMap` assembly and I am seeing the data now. Thanks! If you want, post your answer and i'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The incredibly helpful method for adding mappings from an assembly of another type always trips others up.

For anyone else wondering.. the issue is this:

```
.AddFromAssemblyOf<Product>()
```

`Product` and `ProductMap` were in different assemblies. So the mappings cannot be found in the assembly that `Product` resides in.

I have seen this trip up many people starting out!

Comment: Nice explanation! Haha most people wouldn't put this much effort into writing an answer they already know will get marked as THE answer. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

Also - if you use a SchemaExport to generate the database tables for you - /do/ remember to turn that off the 2nd time you run the application. Otherwise it's blank tables all over again for you...